# What is XOauth and its relationship with OAuth?

Tags: oauth

Some OpenSocial containers use `xoauth_security_token` for signing requests, instead of `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`.

Is XOauth an alternative to OAuth?(*) Who is behind XOauth and where is the official spec?

Casual Googling only lead me to [xoauth.py](http://google-mail-xoauth-tools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/xoauth.py) from google-mail-xoauth-tools project which just states it's a "utilities for XOAUTH authentication".

(*)Aside: it mustn't be, because the container uses other oauth_xxx parameters alongside the xoauth_xxx ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you see the use of **xoauth_security_token**?  I googled it and did not get a single hit.

XOAuth is a SASL authentication mechanism which is based on OAuth signatures.  It can be used for SMTP or IMAP authentication for instance.  There's also a proposal to make it an IETF standard, as an official SASL mechanism.  It is supported by Google and works well with Gmail for SMTP and IMAP access.

For more information how to implement and use it:

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html

HTH.

Comment: Thanks! Regretfully I'm not in the position to disclose where I saw `xoauth_security_token` being used. Now that I think of it, perhaps that x is simply an x as in 'in-house eXtension'..

Comment: Update:  As of Apr 2012, OAuth 1.0 has been deprecated by Google.  Version 2 can be found at:  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Answer (score 1):

XOAUTH is a Microsoft extension to OAuth protocol. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh745374(v=exchg.80).aspx

Is used e.g. in Exchange + Sharepoint + Lync integration.