# XOAuth versus oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

So Gmail supports the XOauth protocol for authorizing an app to use its data. My question is:

Does it have any merit over the normal OAuth mechanism and can I use any of these for getting the access token? Or does Gmail not support the normal OAuth process?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942557/what-is-xoauth-and-its-relationship-with-oauth

Answer (score 2):

For SMTP/IMAP/POP, the xoauth mechanism allows an app to use oauth as an authentication mechanism for those protocols. You can (err, have to :) use the standard oauth flows to have the user authorize your app though.

Note that right now those protocols only work with OAuth 1.0a. OAuth 2.0 support for the xoauth mechanism isn't there yet.

Comment: thanks.So is it that,my app needs to the normal Oauth flow only once per user and the XOauth flow needs to run everytime I want to fetch the inbox